# How to show a GUI message box from a bash script in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, ubuntu, gtk

I'm writing a few little bash scripts under Ubuntu linux. I want to be able to run them from the GUI without needing a terminal window to enter any input or view any output.

So far the only input required is a password for sudo - and gksudo handles that fine.
But I haven't found an easy way to show a message box yet. Is there some kind of 'gkmessage' command available? I'd prefer something present in a default Ubuntu install, but I don't mind installing a new package if necessary.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144924/how-to-create-a-message-box-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 168, accepted):

I believe [Zenity](http://live.gnome.org/Zenity) will do what you want.  It's specifically designed for displaying GTK dialogs from the command line, and it's available as an [Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/zenity).

Comment: `zenity --help` is not so helpful. To make this useful, you need to ensure that you set `--text=My text here` to make it display something...

Comment: E.g. `zenity --info --text="Calculation complete"`

Comment: @Stephen, for some odd reason the correct command is `zenity --help-all`.

Comment: I don't like programs that need to open the display in order to print the help message...

Comment: I use this method to display warnings or errors within my `.xinitrc` while starting my `xorg` server.   Otherwise the errors would be transparent.  I also prefer this `zenity`over `kdialog` since KDE didn't start yet and GTK libs are more lightweight.

Comment: @thoni56 not a real nuisance since all uses of this program need a X display, yet true: `unset DISPLAY ; LC_ALL=C zenity --help-all
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(zenity:32545): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:24:17.177: cannot open display: `

Comment: [zenity docs](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/)

Answer (score 189):

In many Linux distros the `notify-send` command will throw one of those nice perishable notifications in the top right corner. Like so:

`notify-send "My name is bash and I rock da house"`

B.e.a.utiful!

Comment: This works with Fedora as well. I'm pretty certain that any Linux distro can do this.

Comment: Doesn't work on Raspbian GNU/Linux 7. Is there a package that needs to be installed ?

Comment: in the debian repos: apt-cache search notify-osd @carlverbiest

Comment: in Ubuntu 14.04 at least, if call notify-send with timeout 0 like so "notify-send -t 0 'hi there!'" you will get a popup dialog which does not expire.

Comment: In Debian Jessie the `libnotify-bin` package contains the `notify-send` binary. Gnome3 does not appear to require `notify-osd` but I guess other desktop environments may require that in addition to `libnotify-bin`

Comment: This is also available by default on Slackware 14.2

Comment: Works beautifully with LXQt, where none of the other alternatives is installed by default.

Comment: `GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files`

Answer (score 127):

Everyone mentions zenity, there seem to be many others. A mixed up but interesting list is at http://alternativeto.net/software/zenity/

### zenity:

First, an example of zenity featuring text formatting markup, window title, button label.

```
zenity \
--info \
--text="<span size=\"xx-large\">Time is $(date +%Hh%M).</span>\n\nGet your <b>coffee</b>." \
--title="Coffee time" \
--ok-label="Sip"
```

[image: Screenshot]

### gxmessage:

```
gxmessage "my text"
```

[image: Screenshot]

### xmessage:

`xmessage` is very old so it is stable and probably available in all distributions that use X (since it's distributed with X).  It is customizable through X resources, for those that have been using Linux or Unix for long enough to know what it means (`.Xdefaults`, anyone ?).

```
xmessage -buttons Ok:0,"Not sure":1,Cancel:2 -default Ok -nearmouse "Is xmessage enough for the job ?" -timeout 10
```

[image: Screenshot]

### kdialog (KDE tool):

```
kdialog --error "Some error occurred"
```

[image: Screenshot]

### YAD (Yet Another Dialog):

Yad is included in newer Ubuntu versions. There is also this PPA: [YAD: Zenity On Steroids [Display Graphical Dialogs From Shell Scripts] ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/yad-zenity-on-steroids-display.html). Does not seem to auto-size dialogs.

```
echo My text | yad \
--text-info \
--width=400 \
--height=200
```

An bigger example

```
yad \
--title="Desktop entry editor" \
--text="Simple desktop entry editor" \
--form \
--field="Type:CB" \
--field="Name" \
--field="Generic name" \
--field="Comment" \
--field="Command:FL" \
--field="Icon" \
--field="In terminal:CHK" \
--field="Startup notify:CHK" "Application" "Name" "Generic name" "This is the comment" "/usr/bin/yad" "yad" FALSE TRUE \
--button="WebUpd8:2" \
--button="gtk-ok:0" \
--button="gtk-cancel:1"
```

[image: Screenshot]

### Others not in Ubuntu standard repositories:

- shellgui
- xdialog
- gtkdialog

### Off-topic (for terminal):

```
whiptail --msgbox "my text" 10 20
dialog --msgbox "my text" 10 20
```

Feel free to edit.

Comment: Note, [whiptail's `--infobox` has a long standing display bug with xterm (gnome-terminal)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15192893/1695680)

Comment: @ThorSummoner thanks for the tip. For the interested reader, the difference is that `whiptail --infobox` (which does not work properly on terminals that support alternate screen) returns without waiting for user input, while `whiptail --msgbox` (which works) waits for user confirmation before exiting.

Comment: I recall being unsatisfied with msgbox, for my purposes at the time, I think I needed the output to be viewable in a log or something like that;

Comment: A lot of options! Pretty nice examples

Answer (score 51):

The **zenity** application appears to be what you are looking for.

To take input from **zenity**, you can specify a variable and have the output of **zenity --entry** saved to it. It looks something like this:

```
my_variable=$(zenity --entry)
```

If you look at the value in **my_variable** now, it will be whatever was typed in the zenity pop up entry dialog.

If you want to give some sort of prompt as to what the user (or you) should enter in the dialog, add the **--text** switch with the label that you want. It looks something like this:

```
my_variable=$(zenity --entry --text="What's my variable:")
```

Zenity has lot of other nice options that are for specific tasks, so you might want to check those out as well with **zenity --help**. One example is the **--calendar** option that let's you select a date from a graphical calendar.

```
my_date=$(zenity --calendar)
```

Which gives a nicely formatted date based on what the user clicked on:

```
echo ${my_date}
```

gives:

> 08/05/2009

There are also options for slider selectors, errors, lists and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can see `zentity` looks cool. However it isn't part of Ubuntu 12.04, so I went with `gxmessage` instead.

Answer (score 22):

I found the [xmessage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmessage) command, which is sort of good enough.

Comment: That's the granddaddy of them all.

Answer (score 12):

if nothing else is present. you can launch an xterm and echo in it, like this:

```
 xterm -e bash -c 'echo "this is the message";echo;echo -n "press enter to continue "; stty sane -echo;answer=$( while ! head -c 1;do true ;done);'
```

Answer (score 11):

`alert` and `notify-send` seem to be the same thing. I use `notify-send` for non-input messages as it doesn't steal focus and I cannot find a way to stop zenity etc. from doing this.

e.g.

```bash
# This will display message and then disappear after a delay:
notify-send "job complete"

# This will display message and stay on-screen until clicked:
notify-send -u critical "job complete"
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 9):

Here's a little Tcl script that will do what you want.  The Wish interpreter should be installed by default on Ubuntu.

```
#!/usr/bin/wish
pack [label .msg -text [lindex $argv 0]]
pack [entry .ent]
bind .ent <KeyPress-Return> { puts [.ent get]; destroy . }
focus .ent
```

Call it like this:

```
myanswer=`gui-prompt "type your answer and press enter"`
```

Answer (score 8):

There is also `dialog` and the KDE version `kdialog`.  `dialog` is used by slackware, so it might not be immediately available on other distributions.

Comment: `dialog` is available in the Ubuntu repos, and displays a dialog with the terminal (TUI). It's not a GUI.

Answer (score 4):

How about Ubuntu's **alert**. It can be used after any operation to alert it finished and even show red cross icon if operaton was finnished with errors

```
ls -la; alert
```

Comment: `alert` doesn't seem to be included in Ubuntu repositories any more

Answer (score 4):

You can use [shellmarks](https://github.com/shannah/shellmarks) to display a GUI dialog prior to your shell script running, that will allow the user to enter data that will be placed in the environment.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello ${name}"
exit 0
---
[name]
  type="text"
  label="Please enter your name"
  required=true
```

Running script:

```
shellmarks hello.sh
```

[image: Shellmarks dialog]

If you enter "Steve" in the box and press run, the output will be

```
Hello Steve
```

Disclosure:  I'm the author of Shellmarks

Answer (score 3):

[Zenity](http://live.gnome.org/Zenity) is really the exact tool that I think that you are looking for.

or

```
zenity --help
```

Answer (score 0):

Kdialog and dialog are both good, but I'd recommend Zenity. Quick, easy, and much better looking the xmessage or dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I'm liking what I'm seeing with [script-dialog](https://github.com/lunarcloud/script-dialog). It ticks all my boxes, plus some:

- pop up GUI boxes, but has text-mode fallback
- support for various sudo variants (gksudo, kde-sudo, ...)
- can re-launch itself in terminal window

Indeed it's a wrapper for kdialog, zenity, dialog, whiptail and a custom fall-back.

Draw-back is that it doesn't have a CLI, but instead is meant to be sources into a bash script.