# In a bash script/command how can I make a PC beep noise, or play a sound file?

Tags: shell, audio

I have some long running scripts with breaks requiring input/interaction to continue but when I switch to another window I'd like to be notified (by sound) that a task is complete and now awaiting input.

I would prefer to be able to play an audio clip (*.mp3, *.ogg, etc.) but wouldn't care if the only solution is to make the PC Speaker beep noise.

Any ideas? I'm open to any CLI utilities I can install that play sounds that in turn I can execute when needed.

FYI: My System is running WinXP Pro.

***UPDATE:*** Doh! My Windows > Control Panel > Sounds > Default Beep: was set to ***(none)***. Grrr...

Problem solved.

Comment: on  Windows 10 this works for me: `start wmplayer "C:\Windows\Media\Alarm10.wav" && timeout 5 && taskkill /im wmplayer.exe`

Comment: Is this Windows or Linux? You specify Windows, but also bash?

Comment: @Lazerbeak12345 this was cygwin bash running on Windows (XP at the time, now Win10/Win11)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this:

echo ^G

(^G is obtained by ctrl+G).

Note: you can't copy and paste this code in a batch file, it won't work. To obtain a ^G character in a file, type in a cmd window:

echo ^G > beep.txt

(again, ^G is obtained by ctrl+G).

Then you'll have a file named beep.txt, open it with notepad, there will be a square character. This is our ^G once it is saved in a file.

You can then copy and paste it in a batch file to make a sound (don't forget to put "echo" in front of it).

Comment: We're talking about a .bat or .cmd file, right ?
You said you're running windows XP, but you're talking about a "bash" script, which is a linux command interpreter.

Comment: It could be anything I guess... a *.sh, an alias, *.bat or *.cmd.  I should clarify that I'm currently running an alias... which echos a bunch of calls to run *.sh scripts.  So I could put the "sound" bit anywhere in there.

Comment: In most shells (but not command/cmd), you need Ctrl-V Ctrl-G in order to type ^G.

Comment: You can hold "Alt" key, then type "7" on the right side of your keyboard to generate "^G". This simplifies the process of this answer.

Comment: I had to type 07, just 7 makes "•".

Comment: this worked for me, however, I have to put a pause otherwise is so fast that doesnt sound anything. How can I replace the pause? UPDATE: used TIMEOUT command for 2 seconds, and it worked :D

Comment: If your goal is to write a literal bell character in your text editor, you can save an intermediate step and echo ^G|clip to put the character straight into your clipboard.

Answer (score 133):

This will make a beep from within bash

```
echo -en "\007"
```

Comment: Slightly simpler alternatives: `echo -ne '\a'` and `printf '\a'`. Also note that in some Linux distros (e.g., Ubuntu), the bell sound may be suppressed - see http://askubuntu.com/questions/19906/beep-in-shell-script-not-working

Comment: In Cygwin you have to enable beep sound in terminal oprtions.

Comment: In my clearOS server I am using    echo -en "\a" > /dev/console   in a bash script

Comment: If the question specifies Windows XP, why would you give this answer that only works in Linux?

Comment: I don't think it did when I answered the question.

Comment: You can run bash on windows now :-)

Comment: shorter `printf \\a`

Answer (score 39):

**`spd-say`**

```
sleep 2; spd-say 'get back to work'
```

Infinite loop with `-w` if you need extra motivation:

```
sleep 2; while true; do spd-say -w 'get back to work'; done
```

or if you prefer the carrot:

```
sleep 2; while true; do spd-say -t female1 -w "I'm done, come back to me, darling"; done
```

Pre-installed on Ubuntu 14.04 via the package `speech-dispatcher`: http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.manifest for blind people I suppose?

See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/277215/how-to-make-a-sound-once-a-process-is-complete

**Also add a popup**

This combo is a life saver, `b` stands for `beep`:

```
b() ( spd-say 'done'; zenity --info --text "$(date);$(pwd)" & )
```

and then:

```
super-slow-command;b
```

If I'm somewhere in the room, I'll hear it and know that the long job is done.

Otherwise, I'll see the popup when I get back to my computer.

Related:

- [How to show a GUI message box from a bash script in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035/how-to-show-a-gui-message-box-from-a-bash-script-in-linux)
- https://superuser.com/questions/345447/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-when-a-job-process-ends
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/409611/desktop-notification-when-long-running-commands-complete

**Listen to your cooler**

I'm joking of course, but for compilation I noticed that I use often use this queue subconsciously. When the cooler stops humming for a while, it means that the compilation is over!

Comment: I guess you are referring to the Ubuntu platform here, which the links and the version number seems to corroborate.  The OP didn't originally mention any specific platform, though now the question says Windows XP (sic). These things differ between systems; on macOS the command-line speech synthesizer `say` is installed by default; on many other systems, you will probably need to find a package with a different name.  I hear `espeak` is pretty popular on Linux.

Comment: This one spd-say is fun. But the voice quality is not good though.

Answer (score 13):

I know your question was for Window but just putting this here for any **Mac OSX** users who come across this article. OSX 10+ comes with the `say` command:

```
say "I'm done"
```

For example:

```
sleep 5 && say "I'm done waiting 5 seconds"
```

Answer (score 8):

By setting this variable as follows

`PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -en '\a'"`

then bash will beep every time it shows the prompt. When you do not need it anymore,

`unset PROMPT_COMMAND`

Answer (score 7):

To play the system sound from Windows command line you can run:

```
rundll32 user32.dll,MessageBeep
```

It should work on all version of Windows.

Comment: also this `rundll32.exe cmdext.dll,MessageBeepStub`

Comment: The commands for Linux did not work, even tho I'm using the  bash setting in VSCode, but this one did (MessageBeep) gave me the default beep, after some attempts tho

Answer (score 5):

> copy con beep.bat [Enter]
>
> @echo off [Enter]
>
> echo [Ctrl+G] [Enter]
>
> [Ctrl+Z] [Enter]
>
> beep.bat [Enter]

Comment: FYI: Notepad.exe didn't like the ctrl-g, so when I edited this file with notepad and saved, it no longer beeped.  Most likely an ASCII vs Unicode issue.  I then used Notepad++ to edit the file created by typing the commands above, and that worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer without ^G

```
echo -en "\007"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my bash profile I've added a BEEP to the script using @GregReynolds solution above then added this to `PS1`:

```
GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
BEEP=$(echo -en "\007")
export PS1="$GREEN : ${BEEP}"
```

`source ~/.bash_profile` - you should hear the beep after the command prompt returns

I have git-autocomplete on usually so I've provided a much simplified version above

Answer (score 0):

#### On Windows (Cygwin):

Just send a sound file to the DSP, using something like:

```bash
cat /cygdrive/c/Windows/Media/ding.wav > /dev/dsp
```

You don't even need to have sound enabled on *mintty* terminal, as it would go directly to the sound card.