# How to make my Makefile make a sound when all is compiled properly?

Tags: c, makefile

is there was a command on the Makefile for that, and if not is the language used by Makefile open source ? im not too afraid of processor code (if its is language)

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Im using Ubuntu or other POSIX

Comment: `make ... && echo ^G` perhaps? (See: [In a bash script/command how can I make a PC beep noise, or play a sound file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143386/in-a-bash-script-command-how-can-i-make-a-pc-beep-noise-or-play-a-sound-file))

Comment: You probably need to look at this solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19906/beep-in-shell-script-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with makefile itself. makefiles and make, are just tools designed to build files ("targets" in make parlance) with shell commands ("recipes") in an efficient way.   A "phony" target such as `all` should not have a recipe that builds anything, but it can very well play a sound:

`all:` list of targets you want to build

tab play sound in your shell

In this way, the sound command will play only after all the targets listed have updated successfully.