# what does " \a" do in shell substitution in shell script in linux?

Tags: shell, audio, alert

i read about \a escape character.
its description tells that it is basically used for alert or BEL
can anyone tell me that 
is it creates some sound effect?
or please tell me any command that makes CPU to beep a sound

please tell me its necessary for me

Thanx in advanced

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In a bash script/command how can I make a PC beep noise, or play a sound file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143386/in-a-bash-script-command-how-can-i-make-a-pc-beep-noise-or-play-a-sound-file)

Answer (score 0):

it echoes ASCI code 7:

```
$ echo -n $'\a' > file
$ od file
0000000 000007
0000001
```