# Emitting a sound signal on build fail in QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Is it possible to detect build fail and emit a custom sound signal (e.g., via batch file) in QtCreator?

Currently I have a post-build step in my project settings, where I  start a .bat file with sound. When my projects builds successfully, I hear this, everything is ok. When build fails, the post-build step will not be reached, so there is no signal.

So is it possible to make a sound signal for build failure, and how? Or there is no way to do it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character

Comment: thank you for your reply, but how can I connect this bell char with the event?

Comment: @cornhedegehog echo bell symbol via standard console: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143386/in-a-bash-script-command-how-can-i-make-a-pc-beep-noise-or-play-a-sound-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create .bat file and save it somewhere.
Change c:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe to correct path, if you use nmake or mingw-make change it to corresponding pathname

make.bat:

```
c:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe
if errorlevel 1 (
   rundll32 user32.dll,MessageBeep
)
```

In QtCreator go to **Projects** -> **Build & Run** and in the **Build Steps** add **Custom Process Step**. In Command field add path to created make.bat file:

```
Command: C:\<path to your make.bat file>
```

Now deactivate original **Make** step in **Build Steps** and build your project. If return value of process would be greater than 0 you will hier the sound.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.