# Play a sound or notify when npm install is done

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I was thinking , would it be helpful and efficient to get a notification(sound or popup) back after npm finish running a task , a long installation for example . I'm using vscode and running most of my command in the integrated terminal and while waiting for it to finish I ended up spending more time on doing other task that is non-productive.

Comment: Perhaps `npm install; [search on how to make a sound from bash]`, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143386/in-a-bash-script-command-how-can-i-make-a-pc-beep-noise-or-play-a-sound-file) - `;` instead of `&&` since you may want an alert even if it fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So we can break this down to running `npm install`, followed by *some* way of making a sound. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143386/in-a-bash-script-command-how-can-i-make-a-pc-beep-noise-or-play-a-sound-file) thread, a simple beep can be done using:
`echo -en "\007"`.

Combine these two, and you get:
`npm install; echo -en "\007"`

The use of `;` ensures that the beep is played even if `npm install` fails (as opposed to `&&` which only runs the beep if the first command is successful). You could also look here for how to start playing a song with VLC: [play-only-audio-with-vlc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368736/play-only-audio-with-vlc)

Comment: Can we add this such that it is executed after every `npm install` ? Like a global `postinstall` script.

Comment: Unless supported by `npm`, I doubt it is possible. You could create an alias in that case.

Comment: Alias sounds like the way to go here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your `npm install` is [part of a task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_task-autodetection), VSCode 1.72 (Sept. 2022) will offer:

> ### [add audio cue for task end and terminal bell](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/160828)
>
> Fixes "[Play sound upon completion of build so that users can multi-task (do work in other applications) and know when the build has completed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141506) "
>
> Settings `audioCues.taskEnded`

This has been released to [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

For a slightly different solution there is a npm package named [benny-hill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/benny-hill):

> Play the Benny Hill theme while running another command

e.g.

```bash
npx benny-hill npm install
```

will play [Yakety Sax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakety_Sax) while you're waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is [a npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/okimdone) doing exactly what you are asking for:

> Literally tells you when a command is done running.

E.g.

```bash
npx okimdone npm install
```

It depends on external speech to text tools like [espeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net) or [festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/) to produce the audio.

Answer (score 0):

for cmd like Terminals

```bash
Your_Command && [System.Media.SystemSounds]::Beep.Play()
```

Sounds:
Beep, Hand, Quetsion, Asterisk, Exclamation

You can also play the raw sound and changes its pitch and duration
[console]::beep(1000,500)