# Make terminal beep every time a node server is re-compiled & "ready"

Tags: node.js, angular, terminal

Title says it all. How can I make my terminal play a beep or bell sound, when `ng serve` (i.e. node server, for Angular) is compiled and ready?

My application takes like 15-20 seconds to compile, and it would be nice to get an audio hint to go check the browser, if possible.

My application is in Angular, but I presume it'd apply to any node app.

Please note that I'm not looking for a one time beep. It should beep every time the node server picks up a change (and "re-compiles" it and updates the server).

[image]

Comment: Check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59892763/play-a-sound-or-notify-when-npm-install-is-done

Comment: `process.stdout.write(Buffer([0x07]))`

Comment: Just added an edit. I'm not looking for a one time beep. It should beep every time the node server picks up a change (and 're-compiles' it and updates the server).

Comment: (It would be great if you could re-open the question, thanks much)