# How to make a sound in Jupyter with bash kernel

Tags: bash, jupyter

I wish to play a sound when a slow part of analysis in a Jupyter notebook has completed. There are many well-documented ways to do this with the Python kernel in Jupyter (e.g. [Jupyter-Beeper](https://pypi.org/project/Jupyter-Beeper/)). However, the notebook I am working with requires the [Jupyter notebook bash kernel](https://github.com/takluyver/bash_kernel).

[In a bash console, a noise can be played with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143386/in-a-bash-script-command-how-can-i-make-a-pc-beep-noise-or-play-a-sound-file)

```
echo ^G
```

Where ^G is control-G with a special character for control. However, this is not working when I try it in a Jupyter notebook.

How can I play any type of noise in the Jupyter bash kernel, when I am accessing my notebook through a web browser?

Comment: Check if the pcspkr module is loaded: `lsmod | grep pcspkr`. If not, as root do `modprobe pcspkr`. Usually it is not loaded, so check /etc/modprobe.d/backlist.conf if it is listed there.

Comment: `echo -e '\a\a\a\a\a'`?

Comment: pcspkr appears loaded: `lsmod | grep pcspkr`
pcspkr                 12718  0

Comment: `echo -e '\a\a\a\a\a'` is making no sound either