# How to get notice when flutter has compiled

Tags: flutter, automation

I know it may be goofy for some of you, but I really would like to get a notification or a sound when my flutter application has compiled and is running. I would like to automate this process but I don't know where to start or if exists any option to do so?

I have been suggested to use a .sh file to automate execution but It won't show the useful toolbar in VSC.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. There will be many ways you can achieve this.

Simplest way is a bash script.

Step 1.

Create a file **"execute_build.sh"** in the same directory as your application. It can be anywhere but if its elsewhere you need to **"cd"** to that directory which is a long way.

Let's say we have execute_build.sh in same level as pubspec.yaml.

Now. Inside that simple add this line.

```
flutter build apk --release
```

This line can be any release command.

After that line on the next one this bellow line.

```
say "I am done"
```

**Note this would work if you are on Mac os.**
But you can add your own system command based from here: [In a bash script/command how can I make a PC beep noise, or play a sound file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143386/in-a-bash-script-command-how-can-i-make-a-pc-beep-noise-or-play-a-sound-file)

**Since Bash Script execute line by line this second command will only get executed while the above is finished.**

**So Second Line Can be anything.**
It can be a http request using grep to a hook in Slack, Teams.
It can be another python or command that does something else.

To execute this bash script all you have to do is
Write `bash execute_build.sh` in the terminal of the IDE or VS Code.

Comment: I think this is a good idea, I had to be more specific. As I'm using VSC this displays a toolbar once the application start to compile, using ´flutter run´ in the terminal won't display this toolbar.