# How to display infobox in whiptail?

Tags: bash

Why does this code not work in Bash?

```
whiptail --infobox "My Text" 0 0
```

The manual states:

```
whiptail --infobox text height width
```

So what is wrong?

Answer (score 9):

Due to a bug, the `--infobox` option in whiptail doesn't work in an `xterm` (ie. gnome-terminal). It does work on a regular console, however.

This seems to be a long-standing bug, which has been brushed off as non-reproducible when it was [reported](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=91596).

More recently it has again been reported in [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/newt/+bug/604212).

If you need a working `--infobox` under `xterm`, you can use `dialog`.

Comment: Agreed (see my followup in [Whiptail or dialog don't working by ssh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042525/whiptail-or-dialog-dont-working-by-ssh/29711137#29711137)

Comment: whiptail always losing to dialog.

Answer (score 7):

Definitely looks like a bug.

I think it must be saving the screen, displaying the box, but then clearing the screen again (like "less <filename>") - you can see output if you pipe it through something like "cat -v".

I think vt220 is pretty similar to xterm, so a workaround is:

```
TERM=vt220 whiptail --infobox "My Text" 0 0
```

Comment: Great! Only one addition: first try `TERM=ansi` in order to have colors support, then fail to `TERM=vt220` if the previous doesn't work.