# How to create dialog box from script?

Tags: macos, shell

I know that you can create a simple a dialog box from shell script that has text field and two buttons where the one button would start a function that saved the input of the text field(how know how to output text to files but not how to get the input of the text box)?

Comment: Could you clarify your question and post a code attempt?

Comment: google about `whiptail `....

Comment: @Rightleg, I only know that you could use osascript but I got no idea how to attempt this further... PS, thanks I'll check that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show a GUI message box from a bash script in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035/how-to-show-a-gui-message-box-from-a-bash-script-in-linux)